# Google Map API key is behaving erratically

Tags: google-maps, http-referrer

I just moved a website from a subdomain/folder up to "live" status.

My page with an embedded Google Map worked fine up til then, but now, the appearance of the map is only showing in what seems to be a random platform/browser situation.

On my laptop, desktop, and iPhone, the map comes up with no problem. On a colleague's iPhone, he get's an OOPs! error, but sees it alright on his desktop.

At a University lab and my wife's laptop, it's OOPs! again. These all show as referrer errors in the JS console.

I am CONFIDENT that the URLs are identical. I cannot understand how the API key is sensitive to the hardware that's accessing it.

The URL of the map page is: [www.civilwartrails.org/map.html](https://www.civilwartrails.org/map.html).

I suspect(ed) that it may be an SSL issue, but I've seen the OOPs on my wife's laptop where I was sure the page was showing as secure.

Comment: Welcome. Questions about web applications such as Google maps are off topic on this site. Further, your question is a bit broad and needs more detail added. Once that's done, it can be migrated to our sister site, web apps, where it is on topic.

Answer (score 0):

I've since determined that my issues were very much related to the SSL status of the page on various browsers. The site in question is hosted by Network Solutions, and they acknowledged having issues with SSL. It's in the hands of their 'engineering team.' One wrinkle was that I was getting false positives in certain situations where the page looked to be secure, but wasn't. Clearing caches resulted in the page showing as insecure.